# Is four-vector product always Lorentz invariant?

Tags: special-relativity, tensor-calculus

Let's say we have two four-vectors $a^{\mu}$ and $b^{\nu}$.Is it always true that any combination of those 4-vectors (1-rank tensors) multiplied together will yield an invariant quantity (0-rank tensor)? There are plenty of possible combinations: $a^{\mu}b^{\nu}$, $a_{\mu}b^{\nu}$, $a_{\mu}b_{\nu}$, $a_{\mu}a^{\mu}$, $a_{\mu}a_{\mu}$, $a^{\mu}b_{\nu}$, ... I do know that in the case $a_{\mu}a^{\mu}$ you get an invariant, but what happens in other cases?

Comment: You have to contract two copies of the same index to get a scalar, otherwise you have a rank -$2$ tensor.

Comment: So as long as I use same index, no matter which vectors I combine or wether the indeces are up or down, I will get an invariant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get scalars only when you fully contract all indices. By contraction here I mean that you sum over all indices using the Einstein summation convention. Within this convention, expressions such as $a_\mu a_\mu$ do not make sense (contracted indices are always one upper and one lower).

The objects $a_\mu a^\mu$ or $a_\mu b^\mu$ are indeed scalars as the indices are fully contracted.

Expressions such as $a^\mu b^\nu, a_\mu b^\nu, a_\mu b_\nu$ are rank $(2,0), (1,1), (0,2)$ tensors as the indices are not contracted.

Comment: I’m new to all this stuff, and I’d like ask you another question about this. Is there any other forbidden combination of vectors and indeces? And also, whenever all indices are fully contracted (which means they all have a couple in the opposite place they are) you get an invariant? For example if you have two 3-rank tensors T and S with the same indices, T all up and S all down, does that give you an invariant as well? And also, could you explain why?

Comment: @Rainbow (1) The only forbidden things are three or more copies of an index, or two copies at the same height. (2) It's a scalar iff each index appears twice. (These rules are for terms, not sums of them, so e.g $a_\mu a^\mu+b_\mu b^\mu$ is two legal terms, not one forbidden expression with four $\mu$s.)

Comment: @J.G. Ok thanks a lot. You really helped me!

Comment: @Rainbow I guess your questions were answered. To see why these quantities with all the indices contracted are indeed invariants you can look at their transformations under a change of coordinates and you will see they are trivial.